# How do you test Magento performance

Tags: performance, magento

What tools do you use to test Magento hosting performance?
I need a tool to check how many customers website can have at once, with reporting. Also it will be nice if tool can show me page load time (without images and with) and give some advices for performance increase.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.magespeedtest.com/ is quite popular in magento developers community. From time to time I see test results in twitter. You can read article from it's creator, well-known magento community developer Ashley Schroder: http://www.aschroder.com/2011/03/introducing-magespeedtest-com-v2-performance-test-magento-from-4-different-countries/

Comment: Unfortunatly, its free version has limits. Also, I cann't see if it can create reports even in paid version.

Answer (score 0):

Look the below link for magento debuger tool and check your site load time instantiation

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug-8676.html

Answer (score 0):

With magento profiler you can profile even a small block of code. Enable profiler from backend and add following code to profile a code block:

```
Varien_Profiler::start('NameOfFragmentToProfile');
///... here some code we like to get statistics for
Varien_Profiler::stop('NameOfFragmentToProfile');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend you use tools.pingdom.com to test what the load time of a site is from a remote location, but it can't use to test user load.  You can use [seige](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) to test the amount of users that a webserver can handle, but these can not replicate user experience.  If you are looking to test stuff for just text, you can just use the web browser lynx.  That will return your text version only, but can't be used for user load, unless you write something that will use lynx and return times and then build averages.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look at the 2 papers provided by MAgento regarding performance optimisation.

- Optimizing Magento for Peak Performance: Configuring Enterprise
  Edition for Greater Processing Power and Improved Response Times
- Maximizing Performance and Scalability with Magento Enterprise Edition

Here is the link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper

Answer (score 0):

We have a performance profiler tool which is free and doesn't require you to sign up.  It analyses the performance of the page you enter and gives you recommendations on how you can improve it.

http://store.husseycoding.co.uk/profiler

Answer (score 0):

Try gtmetrix

https://gtmetrix.com/

GTmetrix gives you insight on how well your site loads and provides actionable recommendations on how to optimize it